# Proving a property of transposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

I'm studying for a Linear exam and I can't seem to figure out how to prove the following:

$$(λA)^T = \lambda.A^T$$

I'm sure the proof is simple I just can't get it. It should be done without using determinants of any sort.

Comment: Is $\lambda$ a scalar?

Comment: What does transposing do to the matrix elements? How does a scalar act on a matrix? 

Write down an example, it should be really easy and give you an idea of the proof.

Comment: @lisyarus Yes it is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writing $B = (B_{i,j})$ for any matrix $B$, $$[(\lambda A)^T]_{i, j} = (\lambda A)_{j,i} = \lambda A_{j,i}$$ and $$[\lambda A^T]_{i,j} = \lambda (A^T)_{i,j} = \lambda A_{j,i}.$$

Comment: Great that explains it, will accept in 10min. Thank you